# bash if statement keeps changing second argument to literal string

Tags: bash

So I'm not sure why it's doing this. My if statement keeps interpreting the second variable as a literal string instead of a variable. Below is my exact code.

```
lights() {
  bulb1state=$(gatttool -b D8:6F:4B:09:AC:E6 --char-read -a 0x001b)
  echo $bulb1state
  bulb2state=$(gatttool -b DA:5A:4B:09:AC:E6 --char-read -a 0x001b)
  bulb3state=$(gatttool -b AC:E6:4B:07:39:E9 --char-read -a 0x0018)
  bulb4state=$(gatttool -b AC:E6:4B:08:40:50 --char-read -a 0x0018)
  offstate="Characteristic value/descriptor: 00 00 00 00"
  echo $bulb1state
  echo $offstate
  if [ "$offstate" = "$bulb1state" ]; then
    echo $bulb1state
    echo "bulb1 state = off"
    gatttool -b D8:6F:4B:09:AC:E6 --char-write -a 0x001b -n ff000000
    gatttool -b DA:5A:4B:09:AC:E6 --char-write -a 0x001b -n ff000000
    gatttool -b AC:E6:4B:07:39:E9 --char-write -a 0x0018 -n ff000000
    gatttool -b AC:E6:4B:08:40:50 --char-write -a 0x0018 -n ff000000
  fi
}
```

My output:

```
>lights
Characteristic value/descriptor: 00 00 00 00
Characteristic value/descriptor: 00 00 00 00
Characteristic value/descriptor: 00 00 00 00
```

I don't understand why the last 2 echo statements are not displaying.

Edit:
There was a white space on bulb1state. This is good enough for me to find a work around but I'm still curious as why the second term of the if statement was being interpreted as a literal string when I used the "=" operator as opposed to the "-eq" operator. It also didn't matter which variable was first or second.

Comment: Maybe there is an extra space at the end in the return string of `gatttool` (thus in `$bulb1state`).

Comment: The arguments are treated as literal strings because that's what `[ string1 = string2 ]` does. The `-eq` operator, on the other hand, would treat them as integers. What were you expecting it to do?

Comment: @GordonDavisson I'm expecting string2 to be evaluated as the value contained by $bulb1state not be evaluated as "$bulb1state". I know this is happening because my text editor, vim, changes the color of " $bulb1state" to the color of a string rather than the color of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Like I commented, you might have extra spaces in the output of `gatttool` (i.e. `$bulb1state`). For the comparison you should use `=` or `==` (which are equivalents), and for numbers `-eq`, see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/168286/142865).
To ignore the extra spaces you can do (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4277753/1771479)):

```
if [[ "$bulb1state" = "$offstate"* ]]; then
  #...
fi
```

Comment: Like I said, for some reason my second variable is being treated like a literal string. Using that exact statement still has this issue. I found a workaround but thank you for the white spaces comment.